# Queue insert if no connection?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite

I have an app that has to insert some stuff into a mysql database on a server. Sometimes,there might not be an internet connection.>נר<
What I need is some sort of system to queue the insert and when the internet connection and server connection is back to insert it. I need to do this even i my app will be closed and opened.

I thought about doing a local sqlite database,insert the data into it if it can't insert into the mysql server and every 30-60 minutes try to insert the data from sqlite to the mysql server.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could simply store the queries in a text file and run them when you can (with encryption if security is a concern).

Comment: Indeed,an easier way.I'll have to research the encryption thing.I'm using serialization but i guess it is not the same thing

Comment: This is opinion based/application specific!